# Spring Data Jpa Projection with @Query returns no converter found

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to combine projection with `@Query` and I am getting a `NoConverterFoundException`. I cannot find in the documentation where it is specifically not allowed. I know I can project the `Project` to a `ProjectItem` because if I do the same thing without an `@Query` annotation it works. Do I need to specifically register a converter for this?

My Repository Interface

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {
    // Doesn't work?
    @Query("select p from Project p")
    public List<ProjectItem> findAllForTest();
    // Work's okay.
    public List<ProjectItem> findAllBy();
}
```

The DTO:

```
public class ProjectItem {
    private final Integer projectId;
    private final String projectName;
    private final String techstack;
    @JsonCreator
    public ProjectItem(
        @JsonProperty("projectId") Integer projectId, 
        @JsonProperty("projectName") String projectName, 
        @JsonProperty("techstack") String techstack
    ) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.techstack = techstack;
    }
    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }
    public String getTechstack() {
        return techstack;
    }
}
```

And the error

> > 2018-05-07 10:23:02.047 ERROR 9668 --- [o-auto-1-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [employeeproject.model.Project] to type [project.item.ProjectItem]] with root cause

Comment: think you need to use _@Query("new com.example.ProjectItem(p.prop) from Project p")_  or use _List<ProjectItem> findAllProjectedBy_ without a _@Query_

Comment: Thanks. Projection without a query works but I want a query because the query I have is more complicated than the one I have shown here as an example. I can't really put a `ProjectItem(Project p)` constructor because that causes a dependency issue. Like I said, projection works fine without the @Query annotation, shouldn't it work with the @Query annotation as well?

Comment: well If you don't wanna use a constructor you could make aliases that match the projection properties. @Query(select p.prop as projectionprop,.... from  Project p)

Comment: It's a great suggestion and I tried it but I got a different error which was couldn't find `AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap` to `ProjectItem`. I was thinking it would work also! In fact, the actual query I used gave me this error but the shorter "example" query I posted gave the mentioned error. Both `ConverterNotFoundExceptions` but for different reasons.

Comment: should work, just tested it... My guess is you have a mismatch of properties. You could have a try with a very basic projection, just for testing ,like @Query("select p.name as projectname from Project p") Set<PrjectNameProjection>

Comment: Well, I think it might have to do with how you define the DTO for projection. I added the DTO as I'm doing it. It needs to be this way because I want to use the `FeignClient` and that needs the json annotations. I'll try with `Set` but I suspect same issue. Thanks again!

Comment: `Set` or `List`does not make a difference

Comment: "Set or Listdoes not make a difference"  -- Didn't think so but tested anyway and get same results. Difference in DTO methods then since there are several options but I seem to be restricted in what I can use with `FeignClient`.

Comment: Can do `@Query "new project.item.ProjectItem(...) from Project p"` and that works but messy.